# Group mysql results by user

Tags: php, mysql, join, group-by

I want to create a page that lists all the messages sent by current user,and all the messages sent to current user by other members, group the results by user and show their last message (something like sms list):

Mysql tables :

```
users table:
    id,name,password
messages table: 
    id,messageSentedBy,messageSentedTo,messageData
```

Query I tried (returns duplicate messages):

```
select
    users.*,messages.*
from
    messages
left join users on user.name=messages.messageSentedBy
    or user.name=messages.messageSentedTo
where
    messages.messageSentedBy = current user name or
    messages.messageSentedTo = current user name
```

Comment: select distinct users.id,... ?

Comment: This question has been asked on SO *at least* a dozen times before.  Did you search for an answer before posting?

Comment: distint doesnt help much andrey

Comment: maybe you can give an example table and an example output?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this

```
select m.*
from messages m
where 
    (m.sentBy = current user id
     or m.sentTo = current user id)
and not exists (
select 1 
    from messages m2 
    where m2.id > m.id 
    and m2.sentBy = m.sentBy 
    and m2.sentTo=m.sentTo))
order by user.name
```

This is assuming that the message id is a measure of the most recent message (having a timestamped column would be better).

Consider using the user.id as a foreign key rather than the user.name.

Comment: Friso thanks for your comment but its not what i want,
i need to group messages for each user i contact with

Comment: Could you give an example? Given what input, what should the output be?

Comment: Well,basicly just show a page with messages i get from users and send for users,where the messages group for each user lets say im user one,and thers 4 other users,
i sent message to user 2 ,but didnt got an answer from him so show my massage
i sent message to user 3 and he answer me,so show his massage,
user 4 send me a message and i answer him so show my replay to him
user 5 send me a massage whice i didnt answer so show his message

Comment: Somthing like today smartphone sms system,and not like in old days where thers inbox and outbox

Comment: @user3040832 Was this the answer you were looking for?